# Correct way to get allowed arguments from ArgumentParser

Tags: python, argparse

**Question:** What is the intended / official way of accessing possible arguments from an existing `argparse.ArgumentParser` object?

**Example:** Let's assume the following context:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', '-f', type=str)
```

Here I'd like to get the following list of allowed arguments:

```
['-h', '--foo', '--help', '-f']
```

I found the following workaround which does the trick for me

```
parser._option_string_actions.keys()
```

But I'm not happy with it, as it involves accessing a `_`-member that is not officially documented. Whats the correct alternative for this task?

Comment: How important is that initial `existing parser object` part of the question?  Are you making the parser from scratch, or importing it from another module?  Do you need to include the automatic `help` keys?

Comment: I'd like to have the `help` keys as well, but I'm fine with adding them manually. The "existing"-part is the real restriction. I could think or scenarios where it is not possible to user your "dict-trick". So to emphasize, I'm really in a retrieval from an **existing** `ArgumentParser`.

Comment: `_option_string_actions` will be the most reliable source of information for an existing parser.  Just keep in mind how it was populated.   Prefix chars, help SUPPRESS, and groups could alter the `help` layout, and mess with the help search.

Comment: depending on what you want to do, you may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733262/is-there-any-way-to-instruct-argparse-python-2-7-to-remove-found-arguments-fro/35733750#35733750  and parse_known_args.  I've adapted it to add a whole bunch of extra options (like profiling, error dumping, etc...) to my tests, but then turn around and run the standard canned **unittest** and **nosetest** by just stripping out what wasn't desired by them.  In that case, your current parser picks up what it wants to deal with and your legacy/existing parser sees what is left.

Comment: In [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40032361/2747160) I've already used `parse_known_args`. My primary intention was writing something like an auto completion. By now, I've found `argcomplete` which does the [`_actions`-trick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40007285/2747160) (see [here](https://github.com/kislyuk/argcomplete/blob/d3dba1776695db79247aa523243d3f30cbcc9e42/argcomplete/__init__.py#L332)).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a "better" way to achieve what you want.

---

If you really don't want to use the `_option_string_actions` attribute, you could process the `parser.format_usage()` to retrieve the options, but doing this, you will get only the short options names.

If you want both short and long options names, you could process the `parser.format_help()` instead.

This process can be done with a very simple regular expression: `-+\w+`

```
import re

OPTION_RE = re.compile(r"-+\w+")
PARSER_HELP = """usage: test_args_2.py [-h] [--foo FOO] [--bar BAR]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  --foo FOO, -f FOO  a random options
  --bar BAR, -b BAR  a more random option
"""

options = set(OPTION_RE.findall(PARSER_HELP))

print(options)
# set(['-f', '-b', '--bar', '-h', '--help', '--foo'])
```

---

Or you could first make a dictionnary which contains the argument parser configuration and then build the argmuent parser from it. Such a dictionnary could have the option names as key and the option configuration as value. Doing this, you can access the options list via the dictionnary keys flattened with [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.chain):

```
import argparse
import itertools

parser_config = {
    ('--foo', '-f'): {"help": "a random options", "type": str},
    ('--bar', '-b'): {"help": "a more random option", "type": int, "default": 0}
}

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
for option, config in parser_config.items():
    parser.add_argument(*option, **config)

print(parser.format_help())
# usage: test_args_2.py [-h] [--foo FOO] [--bar BAR]
# 
# optional arguments:
#   -h, --help         show this help message and exit
#   --foo FOO, -f FOO  a random options
#   --bar BAR, -b BAR  a more random option

print(list(itertools.chain(*parser_config.keys())))
# ['--foo', '-f', '--bar', '-b']
```

This last way is what I would do, if I was reluctant to use `_option_string_actions`.

Comment: Good advice on how to create an argument parser, greatly improves readability.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the original question, but (the second solution) is a nice workaround. For others to use this, if you only want to allow `--bar`, you need to add it as `('--bar',)` into the `parser_config` because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16449189/2747160). I'll accept this answer, if nothing more elegant appears.

Comment: Collecting the option strings from your own data structure is a good idea.  But it doesn't collect the `help` strings, and doesn't handle an 'existing' parser.

Answer (score 1):

This started as a joke answer, but I've learned something since - so I'll post it.

Assume, we know the maximum length of an option allowed. Here is a nice answer to the question in this situation:

```
from itertools import combinations

def parsable(option):
    try:
        return len(parser.parse_known_args(option.split())[1]) != 2
    except:
        return False

def test(tester, option):
    return any([tester(str(option) + ' ' + str(v)) for v in ['0', '0.0']])

def allowed_options(parser, max_len=3, min_len=1):
    acceptable = []
    for l in range(min_len, max_len + 1):
        for option in combinations([c for c in [chr(i) for i in range(33, 127)] if c != '-'], l):
            option = ''.join(option)
            acceptable += [p + option for p in ['-', '--'] if test(parsable, p + option)]
    return acceptable
```

Of course this is very pedantic as the question doesn't require any specific runtime. So I'll ignore that here. I'll also disregard, that the above version produces a mess of output because [one can get rid of it easily](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2829036/2747160).

But more importantly, this method detected the following interesting `argparse` "features":

- In in the OP example, `argparse` would also allow `--fo`. This has to be a bug.
- But further, in the OP example again, `argparse` would also allow `-fo` (ie. setting `foo` to `o` without space or anything). This is documented and intended, but I didn't know it.

Because of this, a correct solution is a bit longer and would look something like this (only `parsable` changes, I'll omit the other methods):

```
def parsable(option):
    try:
        default = vars(parser.parse_known_args(['--' + '0' * 200])[0])
        parsed, remaining = parser.parse_known_args(option.split())
        if len(remaining)  == 2:
            return False
        parsed = vars(parsed)
        for k in parsed.keys():
            try:
                if k in default and default[k] != parsed[k] and float(parsed[k]) != 0.0:
                    return False  # Filter '-fx' cases where '-f' is the argument and 'x' the value.
            except:
                return False
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

**Summary**: Besides all the restrictions (runtime and fixed maximum option length), this is the only answer that correctly respects the real `parser` behavior - however buggy it may even be. So here you are, a perfect answer that is absolutely useless.

Comment: It's not a bug, see https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argumentparser-objects: By default, `ArgumentParser` permitts unambiguous abbreviated arguments. Set `allow_abbrev` to `False` if you don't like that.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with Tryph's answer.

Not pretty, but you can retrieve them from `parser.format_help()`:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', '-f', type=str)
goal = parser._option_string_actions.keys()

def get_allowed_arguments(parser):
    lines = parser.format_help().split('\n')
    line_index = 0
    number_of_lines = len(lines)
    found_optional_arguments = False
    # skip the first lines until the section 'optional arguments'
    while line_index < number_of_lines:
        if lines[line_index] == 'optional arguments:':
            found_optional_arguments = True
            line_index += 1
            break
        line_index += 1
    result_list = []
    if found_optional_arguments:
        while line_index < number_of_lines:
            arg_list = get_arguments_from_line(lines[line_index])
            if len(arg_list) == 0:
                break
            result_list += arg_list
            line_index += 1
    return result_list

def get_arguments_from_line(line):
    if line[:2] != '  ':
        return []
    arg_list = []
    i = 2
    N = len(line)
    inside_arg = False
    arg_start = 2
    while i < N:
        if line[i] == '-' and not inside_arg:
            arg_start = i
            inside_arg = True
        elif line[i] in [',',' '] and inside_arg:
            arg_list.append(line[arg_start:i+1])
            inside_arg = False
        i += 1
    return arg_list

answer = get_allowed_arguments(parser)
```

There's probably a regular expressions alternative to the above mess...

Comment: There is indeed a a simple regex which makes it easier: `-+\w+`. used with findall(), it returns all the options in the help message.

Answer (score 0):

First a note on the `argparse` docs - it's basically a how-to-use document, not a formal API.  The standard for what `argparse` does is the code itself, the unit tests (`test/test_argparse.py`), and a paralyzing concern for backward compatibility.

There's no 'official' way of accessing `allowed arguments`, because users usually don't need to know that (other than reading the `help/usage`).

But let me illustrate with a simple parser in an iteractive session:

```
In [247]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [248]: a = parser.add_argument('pos')
In [249]: b = parser.add_argument('-f','--foo')
```

`add_argument` returns the Action object that it created.  This isn't documented, but obvious to any one who has created a parser interactively.

The `parser` object has a `repr` method, that displays major parameters.  But it has many more attributes, which you can see with `vars(parser)`, or `parser.<tab>` in Ipython.

```
In [250]: parser
Out[250]: ArgumentParser(prog='ipython3', usage=None, description=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True)
```

The Actions too have `repr`; the Action subclass is determined by the `action` parameter.

```
In [251]: a
Out[251]: _StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='pos', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
In [252]: b
Out[252]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['-f', '--foo'], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
```

`vars(a)` etc can be used to see all attributes.

A key `parser` attribute is `_actions`, a list of all defined Actions.  This is the basis for all parsing.  Note it includes the `help` action that was created automatically.  Look at `option_strings`; that determines whether the Action is positional or optional.

```
In [253]: parser._actions
Out[253]: 
[_HelpAction(option_strings=['-h', '--help'], dest='help', nargs=0, const=None, default='==SUPPRESS==', type=None, choices=None, help='show this help message and exit', metavar=None),
 _StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='pos',....),
 _StoreAction(option_strings=['-f', '--foo'], dest='foo', ...)]
```

`_option_string_actions` is a dictionary, mapping from `option_strings` to Actions (the same objects that appear in `_actions`).  References to those Action objects appear all over the place in `argparse` code.

```
In [255]: parser._option_string_actions
Out[255]: 
{'--foo': _StoreAction(option_strings=['-f', '--foo'],....),
 '--help': _HelpAction(option_strings=['-h', '--help'],...),
 '-f': _StoreAction(option_strings=['-f', '--foo'], dest='foo',...),
 '-h': _HelpAction(option_strings=['-h', '--help'], ....)}

In [256]: list(parser._option_string_actions.keys())
Out[256]: ['-f', '--help', '-h', '--foo']
```

Note that there is a key for each `-` string, long or short; but there's nothing for `pos`, the positional has an empty `option_strings` parameter.

If that list of keys is what you want, use it, and don't worry about the `_`.  It does not have a 'public' alias.

I can understand parsing the `help` to discover the same; but that's a lot of work to just avoid using a 'private' attribute.  If you worry about the undocumented attribute being changed, you should also worry about the help format being changed.  That isn't part of the docs either.

`help` layout is controlled by `parser.format_help`.  The `usage` is created from information in `self._actions`.  Help lines from information in

```
    for action_group in self._action_groups:
        formatter.add_arguments(action_group._group_actions)
```

(you don't want to get into `action groups` do you?).

There is another way of getting the `option_strings` - collect them from the `_actions`:

```
In [258]: [a.option_strings for a in parser._actions]
Out[258]: [['-h', '--help'], [], ['-f', '--foo']]
```

===================

Delving in to code details a bit:

`parser.add_argument` creates an Action, and then passes it to `parser._add_action`.  This is the method the populates both `.actions` and  `action.option_strings`.

```
    self._actions.append(action)
    for option_string in action.option_strings:
        self._option_string_actions[option_string] = action
```

Comment: I was aware of the `add_argument` return value. But swapping one private member with another one won't help...

Comment: Though I would argue that the `_action` list is more basic.  Not that either private attribute is going to be changed in the next 10 years of releases.  They are too important to the `parser` functionality.