# How to check if an ArgumentParser contains an argument?

Tags: python, argparse

After I've created my argument parser. How can I check if the parser contains a rule for an argument. Here's some code to explain what I mean.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo')
parser.add_argument('--bar')

'foo' in parser
# => True
'bar' in parser
 # => True
'baz' in parser
 # => False
```

In short, I want to know if an argument exists in the parser.

As part of my program initialisation I am loading several configuration files. If there are settings in the config files which are not in the parser I want to warn the user.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39996295/correct-way-to-get-allowed-arguments-from-argumentparser should help.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks! I don't know why that question didn't appear when I searched. I've marked this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit clunky, but you could run [`parse_args`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args) with not arguments and extract the keys for the resulting `Namespace` object:

```
>>> 'foo' in vars(parser.parse_args())
True
>>> 'baz' in vars(parser.parse_args())
False
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. One problem with this in my case is I'm using `default=argparse.SUPPRESS` so settings which a user doesn't specify won't overwrite the config files. I've closed the question as it appears to be a duplicate - and the other question has quite a few answers.