# Removing arguments from python/argparse (without using parse_known_args)

Tags: python, argparse

I have two programs, one is a wrapper of the other.

Main program has args order-arg-one, --arg1, --arg2
Wrapper program has all the args of main program, and additional args --arg3 , --arg4

I want to be able to pass the arguments from the wrapper to the main program without getting an 'argument not recognized' error. However, I do *not* want to use parse_known_args, because then the user receives zero feedback if they made a typo or used a nonsensical argument. (I have already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733262/is-there-any-way-to-instruct-argparse-python-2-7-to-remove-found-arguments-fro))

Other than manually searching for every single argument name, and then any value coming immediately after that name if the name is present and its an argument that expects a parameter after is, is there a more elegant way of cleaning my arguments of some set of values in order to pass them on to another parser?

Comment: Give some example code to make clear what's going on.  If the wrapper handles all arguments, it doesn't matter whether the main ignores the ones it can't handle.  In the linked answer the first parser uses partial, and passes the extras to the second.  You might try a dummy parser that captures `arg3/4` and passes the rest as its `extras`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of mixing various partial parsings:

```
import argparse

def foo(parser, alist):
   for arg in alist:
        parser.add_argument('--'+arg, action='store_true')

parser1 = argparse.ArgumentParser()
foo(parser1, ['arg1','arg2'])

parser2 = argparse.ArgumentParser()
foo(parser2, ['arg3','arg4'])

parser12 = argparse.ArgumentParser()
foo(parser12, ['arg1','arg2','arg3','arg4'])

args = parser12.parse_args()
print('p12', args)

args, extras = parser2.parse_known_args()
print('p2',args, extras)

args = parser1.parse_args(extras)
print('p1',args)

args, extras = parser1.parse_known_args()
print('p1p',args, extras)
```

None:

```
1714:~/mypy$ python3 stack47866170.py 
p12 Namespace(arg1=False, arg2=False, arg3=False, arg4=False)
p2 Namespace(arg3=False, arg4=False) []
p1 Namespace(arg1=False, arg2=False)
p1p Namespace(arg1=False, arg2=False) []
```

all:

```
1722:~/mypy$ python3 stack47866170.py --arg1 --arg2 --arg3 --arg4
p12 Namespace(arg1=True, arg2=True, arg3=True, arg4=True)
p2 Namespace(arg3=True, arg4=True) ['--arg1', '--arg2']
p1 Namespace(arg1=True, arg2=True)
p1p Namespace(arg1=True, arg2=True) ['--arg3', '--arg4']
```

subsets

```
1723:~/mypy$ python3 stack47866170.py --arg1 --arg2
p12 Namespace(arg1=True, arg2=True, arg3=False, arg4=False)
p2 Namespace(arg3=False, arg4=False) ['--arg1', '--arg2']
p1 Namespace(arg1=True, arg2=True)
p1p Namespace(arg1=True, arg2=True) []
1723:~/mypy$ python3 stack47866170.py --arg1 --arg3
p12 Namespace(arg1=True, arg2=False, arg3=True, arg4=False)
p2 Namespace(arg3=True, arg4=False) ['--arg1']
p1 Namespace(arg1=True, arg2=False)
p1p Namespace(arg1=True, arg2=False) ['--arg3']
```

error - caught by `parser12`:

```
1724:~/mypy$ python3 stack47866170.py --arg1 --foo
usage: stack47866170.py [-h] [--arg1] [--arg2] [--arg3] [--arg4]
stack47866170.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --foo
```

Comment: This works great with only optional args, but if there are positional arguments for each parser it's not a solution... Nonetheless, accepting

Comment: yes, positions will be hard handle when using several parsers.  It might work if only parsed those.

Comment: It is an interesting idea to use multiple parsers to parse the same arguments. In some cases it could be very useful. --- The downside is the case when I need to put the same (more complicated) argument definition to multiple parsers. Is there a simple way how to copy an argument definition (I think it is represented by `argparse.Action` object) from one parser to another?

Comment: @pabouk, the `parents` mechanism does this - copying `Action` references from the parent to the child.  I don't offhand recall which method does this (probably in the Actions_container class).  So even if you don't want to use `parents` you can copy ideas from this.